# Hard coded values to web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, web-config

i already have a phpcode with hard coded values,

```
$username = "abcd";
$password = "abcd123";
```

now i wanted  to put those values to web.config file.here is my work,but something wrong here.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="username" username="abcd"/>
<add key="password" password="abcd123"/>
<appSettings/>
```

so.. is there any problem ? and i also wanted to know how can i take this settings to aspx.cs file.. i mean [configurationmanager] something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare them with the key and value properties instead, like so:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="username" value="abcd"/>
   <add key="password" value="abcd123"/>
<appSettings/>
```

If you want the basics, you can access the keys via:

```
string username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
```

To access my web config keys I always make a static class in my application. It means I can access them wherever I require and I'm not using the strings all over my application (if it changes in the web config I'd have to go through all the occurrences changing them). Here's a sample:

```
using System.Configuration;

public static class AppSettingsGet
{    
    public static string Username
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString(); }
    }

    public static string Password
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) :

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
```

Comment: in the aspx.cs file do samething ? isnt there any brackets in WebConfigurationManager ? eg [WebConfigurationManager].AppSetting["username"] ?

Answer (score 1):

Its not safe to hard code the values to web.config file.For passwords store the Hash Value Instead of Original string.Also try to use the DPAPI.

Answer (score -1):

When thosethings done.. after that is needed below things to do ? here i create a instance.or how to access/call web.config's connection string in my page.

```
 internal static ConnectionFactory newinstance()
    {
        try
        {
            return new   ConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConString"].ConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```